# How to setup Elsa workflow using .Net 6.0 or above?

Tags: asp.net-core, elsa-workflows

I'm new in Elsa Workflow. I try to set up a simple Hello World REST API following the steps in the URL below:

https://elsa-workflows.github.io/elsa-core/docs/next/quickstarts/quickstarts-aspnetcore-hello-world

However, when I set up the project using `dotnet`, no Startup.cs is found. I check my dotnet version using `dotnet --version`, it shows 7.0.100. I search the web, it said that `Startup.cs` is removed and no longer required in Web App, starting from .Net 6.0 onwards.

My question is:

1. **Do I need to install the old .Net Core 3.1 to make Elsa work?**
2. **If not, how do I set up a simple Elsa workflow using .Net 7.0?**

I've tried to move the code in `Startup.cs` into `Program.cs` as below:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services
    .AddElsa(options => options
    .AddHttpActivities()    
    .AddWorkflow<ElsaQuickstarts.WebApp.HelloWorld.HelloWorld>());

var app = builder.Build();

app.Run();
```

But when I build the program and run, it gives the following error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find the required services. Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddAuthorization' in the application startup code.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.AuthorizationAppBuilderExtensions.VerifyServicesRegistered(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.AuthorizationAppBuilderExtensions.UseAuthorization(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.ConfigureApplication(WebHostBuilderContext context, IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Git\ElsaQuickstarts.WebApp.HelloWorld\Program.cs:line 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `AddAuthorization` to the services and call `UseHttpActivities` to add Elsa's middleware to handle HTTP requests to workflows:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services
    // ...
    .AddAuthorization();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpActivities();

app.Run();
```

Comment: The error is gone and the application is started successfully. However, when I call from the browser with URL = `http://localhost:<port assigned when program start>/hello-world`, it returns 404. Anything I need to change as well?

Comment: Call UseHttpActivities() method too as per official example. I've updated my answer.